# .map() no retorna data en el navegador - ReactJS

Tags: javascript, array, reactjs, foreach, map

Al usar .map() e iterando un objeto, cuando quiero visualizar la data en el navegador no retorna nada, aparece la pantalla en blanco, alguna solución para este problema?

```
const Shipping = (props) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useCustomFetch("/send");
  let valueSend = Object.values(data);

  return (

    <div>
      {valueSend.map((send) => {
        if (send.id_envio === props.data.id_envio) {
          return (
            <div key={send.id_envio}>
              <p>Id envio numero {send.id_envio}</p>
              <p>Estado del envio: {send.estado}</p>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: Ya validaste que ambos valores si sean iguales y que exista al menos un elemento que lo cumpla?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que probablemente te esté ocurriendo, es que no estás esperando a que la petición finalice antes de invocar:

```javascript
let valueSend = Object.values(data);
```

por lo que desafortunadamente estás obteniendo un arreglo completamente vacío o un error, si dentro del *hook* que has implementado inicializas el estado que contiene los datos a `null`, el resultado de `Object.values( null )` da directamente un error y en caso de que lo inicialices con un objeto vacío obtendrás también una lista vacía, por eso no estás obteniendo ningún resultado.

Prueba a utilizar el estado del mismo objeto `data` que te permitirá saber cuando están listos tus datos:

```javascript
const Shipping = (props) => {
  const { data, loading, error } = useCustomFetch("/send");

  return (

    <div>
      { data && Object.values(data).map((send) => {
        if (send.id_envio === props.data.id_envio) {
          return (
            <div key={send.id_envio}>
              <p>Id envio numero {send.id_envio}</p>
              <p>Estado del envio: {send.estado}</p>
            </div>
          );
        }
      })}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Este fragmento te funcionará siempre y cuando inicialices tu estado `data` a `null`. Al no conocer la implementación de tu *hook* puede que esto resuelva (o no resuleva) tu problema por completo.

Te dejo también un enlace que te puede resultar de gran ayuda sobre [como crear *hooks* personalizados para hacer peticiones en *React*](https://dev.to/shaedrizwan/building-custom-hooks-in-react-to-fetch-data-4ig6)